# Comparison of HTML including handling singleton elements

Tags: c#, html

I know that this has to be something with a simple solution, but I'm finding myself banging my head against it. I'm trying to write regression tests for some HTML pages generated by my company's application. They're unlikely to change frequently, but we do want checks to ensure that the correct page is displayed for every country. My impulse is to pull the HTML from the approved pages and then use Selenium to check the values. The problem I'm running into is that pulling the HTML up on different browsers yields different results when it comes to [singleton elements](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/html-void-elements.htm), both the void ones and the ones that simply don't require an ending tag such as `<P>` and `<HR>`. Thus, I can't just do a text compare, and even packages such as [HtmlDiff](https://htmldiff.codeplex.com/) show that there's a change.

Due to the occasional lack of closing tags, my attempt to fix things by pulling the text into an XML document and then re-exporting it failed. I've had some small success with monkeying with the input to add closing tags, but I'm not an HTML or XML expert, so it feels like I'm trying to patch things with band-aids that may or may not distort the results.

Is there a simple and free solution I can use for comparing two HTML pages with the same style and check for actual equivalence despite differences in singleton elements?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and write custom Javascript to check the conformance of the pages with what you want.
(In general for this task i think every headless browser can be helpful.)